Node fs file does not exist
I have the following code to read a file in my project with Node fs.
 const files: FileSystemTree = {
      "Component.tsx": {
        file: {
          contents: fs.readFileSync(
            `../../apps/components/${name.toLowerCase()}/${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}.tsx`
          )
        }
      }
    };

Which is part of the overall class:
import {WebContainer, FileSystemTree} from "@webcontainer/api";
import fs from "fs";

export default class Container {
  private mContainer!: WebContainer;

  constructor() {
    this.CreateContainer();
    this.ScaffoldViteApp();
    this.StartDevServer();
  }

  private CreateContainer = async () => {
    try {
      this.mContainer = await WebContainer.boot();
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  }; 

  private ScaffoldViteApp = async () => {
    try {
      this.mContainer.spawn("npm", [
        "create",
        "vite",
        "container-example -- --template react-swc-ts"
      ]);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  };

  private StartDevServer = async () => {
    try {
      this.mContainer.spawn("npm", ["run", "dev"]);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  };

  public SetComponent(name: string) {
    const files: FileSystemTree = {
      "Component.tsx": {
        file: {
          contents: fs.readFileSync(
            `../../apps/components/${name.toLowerCase()}/${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}.tsx`
          )
        }
      }
    };

    console.log(fs.readFileSync(
        `../../apps/components/${name.toLowerCase()}/${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}`
      ))

    try {
      this.mContainer.fs.mkdir("components");
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    try {
      this.mContainer.mount(files, {mountPoint: "components"});
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  }

  public GetIframe() {
    return this.mContainer.on("server-ready", (port, url) => {
      return url;
    });
  }

  public WriteComponent(name: string, content: string) {
    const files: FileSystemTree = {
      "Component.tsx": {
        file: {
          contents: content
        }
      }
    };

    try {
      this.mContainer.mount(files, {mountPoint: "components"});
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    return this.mContainer;
  }
}

When I use vitest to run: Container.SetComponent() I get an error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../apps/components/example/Example'

However, upon commanding clicking the path it does in fact exist. I have tried the same thing with a .tsx ending to no avail. I have also tried running the file  with ts-node and tsx and I get the same results. Here is my project structure:
.
├── README.md
├── apps
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── example
│   │   │   ├── Example.tsx
│   │   │   ├── stories
│   │   │   │   └── Example.stories.tsx
│   │   │   └── tests
│   │   │       └── example.spec.tsx
│   │   └── project.json
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── astro.config.mjs
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   ├── @astrojs
│   │   │   │   ├── check -> ../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@astrojs+check@0.7.0_prettier@3.2.5_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@astrojs/check
│   │   │   │   └── starlight -> ../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@astrojs+starlight@0.23.2_astro@4.9.2_@types+node@20.12.13_terser@5.31.0_typescript@5.4.5_/node_modules/@astrojs/starlight
│   │   │   ├── astro -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.9.2_@types+node@20.12.13_terser@5.31.0_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/astro
│   │   │   ├── sharp -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/sharp@0.32.6/node_modules/sharp
│   │   │   └── typescript -> ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/typescript
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   ├── public
│   │   │   └── favicon.svg
│   │   └── src
│   │       ├── assets
│   │       │   └── houston.webp
│   │       ├── content
│   │       │   ├── config.ts
│   │       │   └── docs
│   │       │       ├── components
│   │       │       │   └── example.mdx
│   │       │       ├── guides
│   │       │       │   └── example.md
│   │       │       └── index.mdx
│   │       └── env.d.ts
│   └── storybook
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── project.json
│       ├── tsconfig.json
│       └── tsconfig.storybook.json
├── docs
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── highlight.css
│   │   ├── icons.js
│   │   ├── icons.svg
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   ├── navigation.js
│   │   ├── search.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── functions
│   │   └── default.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── modules.html
│   └── types
│       └── Props.html
├── eslint.config.js
├── index.css
├── nx.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── docs-sandbox
│   │   ├── createContainer.ts
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   └── tests
│   │       └── createContainer.spec.ts
│   ├── etech-ui-dev
│   │   └── project.json
│   └── etech-ui-utils
│       └── project.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
├── postcss.config.cjs
├── reactDocgen.ts
├── tailwind.config.js
├── tests
│   └── setup.ts
├── tsconfig.astro.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.node.json
├── tsconfig.react.json
├── types
│   └── eslint-plugin-react.d.ts
└── vite.config.ts


What do you get if you do console.log(path.resolve('../../my/path/here'))? Does the path look like you expect?

Yes the output is apps/components/example/Example.tsx

You sure? path.resolve says it resolves to an absolute path: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths but that doesn't look like an absolute path

It was absolute I trimmed the path

So if you copy that absolute path and run ls path/you/copied/here then you get a result? I'm trying to ascertain that the path being resolved is indeed the correct path. Which I can't know from your question since I don't have your directory structure or your absolute path.

Here is the full absolute path: /Users/e***h/git/etech-ui/apps/components/example/Example.tsxI also added my project structure

This is probably because paths in node are relative to the current working directory (where you invoked the command to launch the node executable) and not from the file with the path in it.
So you probably either want this, if apps is in the root of your project where you are running this command from:
apps/components/path/here

Or perhaps this if you want it to be relative to the current file:
path.join(__dirname, '../../app/components/path/here')
// or if using es modules
path.join(import.meta.dirname, '../../app/components/path/here')


When I use path.join I get an error ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope

If you are using ES modules, then I think you need import.meta.dirname instead. See: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#no-__filename-or-__dirname. Also that issue has a lot of answers on stack overflow already if want to learn more about that.
